# How to format CASE date format

Tags: case

is my date format incorrect?

```
CASE WHEN ({custentity92} TO_DATE(‘1.1.16’, 'MM.DD.YYYY')) < 0 
  THEN ({jobprice}-{custentity_proj_unbilled}+{custentity94}) 
END
```

Comment: This appears to be SQL syntax. What is the DBMS?

Comment: Oracle SQL for NetSuite platform